# How to safely remove noto fonts in Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, xfce, fonts

Is there a way to safely remove noto-fonts from the system? They were installed by some package automatically, but they make it horrible to select fonts in any program, as about 1800 of the possible fonts are of the noto family, which I'm probably never going to use.
Libreoffice, Inkscape... everything becomes full of them:

[image]

searching my system, I found the packages `fonts-noto-core fonts-noto-extra fonts-noto-mono fonts-noto-ui-core` and a folder with 1847 noto fonts in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/`

If I remove any of the packages, the system seems to lose some important fonts, as even the terminal becomes full of squares where characters should appear:
[image]

So, is it possible to remove (atleast) most of these fonts without breaking the system? If there is someplace to change the configuration to completely avoid these fonts, so I can remove them, I'd prefer.

I'm in Debian Testing (Bookworm) and XFCE

Answer (score 2):

I found it. Truth is, these fonts aren't required anywhere, they just are used if they're available.

`fonts-noto-core fonts-noto-extra fonts-noto-ui-core` are installed by LibreOffice. And I'm not sure, but my best guess is that `fonts-noto-mono` are installed by Python3.

To solve the problem, I removed the first three packages (the ones that come with LibreOffice) through apt-get, and when everything became unreadable, I simply rebooted. At startup, Debian probably just used some other available font.
I kept the `fonts-noto-mono` package, as it consists of only 3 font files.

The command to remove the fonts in the terminal (for Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/other distros based on Debian) is

```
sudo apt-get remove fonts-noto-core fonts-noto-extra fonts-noto-ui-core
```

And to make things easier and reboot as soon as the fonts are removed:

```
sudo apt-get remove fonts-noto-core fonts-noto-extra fonts-noto-ui-core && sudo reboot
```

Now ONLY IF for some reason, after the reboot the system still show glitched fonts, reinstall them:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-noto-core fonts-noto-extra fonts-noto-ui-core
```

Even if the command can't be read in the terminal, it will work. Just copy/paste, wait a second and type your password + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Wait about more 5 seconds, and it will ask to type y/n (or other letters, depending on the system language). Type 'y' and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: Anyone know if this will negatively affect KDE?